# parameter or call from vb6 to sql code

Tags: mysql, sql, parameters, vb6, call

I am about to make a system using VB6. My instructor told me that I should use a parameter or a call from SQL code because we need to focus on sql. My question is how to do this? I know about ADO ,RDO, etc ... but i'm having a hard time looking for something like this. Any advise or clue on how to do this? Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to make a call from your VB Application to which DB?

Comment: Well im still thinking about it but i have 3 choices, MSACCESS, phpmyadmin, and mysql workbench. But, i think phpmyadmin is my priority.

Comment: @scarface23 Out of those three that you've mentioned only one is RDBMS (MS Access), two others are IDE tools for MySql.

Comment: @paterm: thanks man, now it's between access and sql server ..Maybe il just use ms access anyway we are assigned to do simple system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the right driver which goes well with your database installed/available first. This would then be avialable in the References dialog box.

For ADO, set a reference to the appropriate ADO type library. There are two ADO type libraries. One is called ADODB and is contained in MSADO15.DLL. The other is called ADOR and is contained in MSADOR15.DLL.

ADODB is the larger and more feature-rich of the two. It contains the main ADO objects and is the one you'll probably want to use mostly. The second is a "lightweight" subset of the ADODB type library that supports only recordsets. You can use if your operations are limited to recordsets.

A good set of examples are found in [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)